# PHPStorm not receiving debug connection when accessing the web server from a remote host

Tags: apache-http-server, php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

For some reason PHPStorm does not receive the debug connection when accessing the web server from a remote host. PHPStorm behaves like it is not listening at all.
If I access the web server from the same host the debug connection is accepted and it breaks at first line which is expected behavior.

---

My current setup:

**Host machine**: Windows 10 PRO, Chrome browser, Firewall disabled (for the sake of testing)

**Guest machine**: Ubuntu 18.04 installed on a Hyper-v VM on the host machine

Inside the guest machine I have Docker installed which is running the following containers:

- php-fpm 7.2.16
- apache-httpd 2.4

PHP-FPM is configured to use port 9000 while XDEBUG 9009.

PHP Config:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9009
```

Apache fcgi config:

```
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>

<Proxy "fcgi://${PHP_SERVER_NAME}:${PHP_SERVER_FCGI_PORT}" enablereuse=on max=10>
</Proxy>

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://${PHP_SERVER_NAME}:${PHP_SERVER_FCGI_PORT}"
</FilesMatch>
```

PHPStorm is as installed on the Ubuntu guest machine.

---

So to summarize:

When accessing the website from Chrome/Firefox on the guest machine PHPStorm receives the connection and breaks as expected.

When doing the exact same thing from host machine, the website is rendered without PHPStorm accepting the connection.

So my question is what could cause the issue to not create the debug connection when accessing from host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `xdebug.remote_connect_back` with `xdebug.remote_host` seems to solve the issue.

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host = IP_OF_HOST_RUNNING_PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_port = 9009
```

From my understanding the reason why remote_connect_back didn't work is because of the following:

> If enabled, the xdebug.remote_host setting is ignored and Xdebug will try to connect to the client that made the HTTP request. It checks the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variables to find out which IP address to use.
>
> If xdebug.remote_addr_header is configured, then the $SERVER variable with the configured name will be checked before the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variables.
>
> Source https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings

So with `xdebug.remote_connect_back` the debugger sends the debug connection to the IP of the REQUESTER which in this case was the HOST and not the GUEST.